# React state increment not updating view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following:

```
class PickColor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            active: 0
        }

        this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
    }

    setActiveClass () {
        this.setState({ active:this.state.active + 1 })
    }

    backToPrevious (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.actionID(1);
        this.props.activeNav('case-0');
    }
    goToNext (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.actionID(3);
        this.props.activeNav('case-2');
        this.props.setNavB(true);
        this.props.setIconsHolderOnOff(true);
    }
    getColorValue(event) {
        var color_id = event.target.getAttribute("data-color-name");
        this.props.colorName(color_id);
        this.props.setColorTextID(event.target.getAttribute("data-color-id"));
        this.setActiveClass();
    }
    getColorFromCode(color){
        var className;

        switch (color) {
            case "fc0d1b":
                className = 'red';
            break;
            case "fed343":
                className = 'yellow';
            break;
            case "2afd82":
                className = 'green';
            break;
            case "2af3fd":
                className = 'blue';
            break;
            case "a025fb":
                className = 'purple';
            break;
        }

        return className;
    }
    getActiveForm () {
        if (this.props.show === 2) {
            return "show-form";
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }   
    }

    render () {
        console.log(this.state.active);
        var activeForm = this.getActiveForm(this.props.show);
        var colorsLink = [],
            that = this,
            colorInfo ;

        this.props.colors.forEach(function(el, i) { 
            colorsLink.push(<li 
                                data-color-id={el.id}
                                data-color-name={that.getColorFromCode(el.background_color)}
                                className={that.props.active == i ? 'active' : '' + that.getColorFromCode(el.background_color)} 
                                key={el.background_color} 
                                onClick={that.getColorValue.bind(that)}>
                            </li>
            );
        });

        if (this.props.currentState.activeColorTextID != "") { 
            colorInfo = <ColorInfo colors={this.props.colors} colorID={this.props.currentState.activeColorTextID}  />
        }

        return (
            <section className={"colors form " + activeForm}>
                <h2>Pick your<br /> color</h2>
                <ul>
                    {colorsLink}
                </ul>
                <div className="color-info-wrapper">
                    {colorInfo}
                </div>
                <button className="back" onClick={this.backToPrevious.bind(this)}><span>back</span></button>
                <button className="next" onClick={this.goToNext.bind(this)}><span>continue</span></button>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to assigna class of active onClick but it doesn't seem to get added at all.

Comment: can you try with className={\`colors form ${activeForm}\`} ? Please be aware that it is \`, not '. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Any chance you can add the code for the parent component, given the fact you are making calls to methods on it that directly affect the logic in this one?

Comment: @AndreiNeagu I have tried but all I get is colors and form

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referencing `props.active` instead of `state.active`... otherwise, I'm not sure the point of having `active` in state.

```
className={that.props.active == i ? 'active' : '' + that.getColorFromCode(el.background_color)}
```

should be `that.state.active == i ? 'active' ...`

Also, you could simplify your `colorsLink` array to be created from a map instead of iterating on the list and using pushes. Maps return a new array, you're doing it manually by combining `forEach` and `push`.

```
var colorsLink = this.props.colors.map(function(el, i) { 
    return <li 
                data-color-id={el.id}
                data-color-name={that.getColorFromCode(el.background_color)}
                className={that.state.active == i ? 'active' : '' + that.getColorFromCode(el.background_color)} 
                key={el.background_color} 
                onClick={that.getColorValue.bind(that)}>
           </li>;
    });
```